# Problems installing packages on PyCharm

Tags: python

I'm having a number of problems installing packages on PyCharm.

Such as:

- Scrappy, error message = SyntaxError: invalid syntax
- Lxml, error message = ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
- Libxml2-python, error message = Non-zero exit code (1)

Is there a reason I keep getting error messages and what can I do about it?

Comment: Could add more detail, please. What are the steps you are doing before you get the errors ?

Comment: Have you got actual `pip` version?

Comment: @Mino_e I re-installed an everything works fine, thank you for your response!

Comment: @DanteVoronoi I re-installed an everything works fine, thank you for your response!